# List index out of range even though it's not

Tags: python, list, csv, file, range

I have a code that I wrote in order to process data from some experiments. The data is usually stored in .csv files, with several columns and many rows. At some point I need to look at a certain column and process values only in this column. In order to do that, I reference to it by `row[N]`, where N is the number of a column that I need to process. I've successfully processed 11 out of 12 files and then on the last file got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 63, in <module>
    brdn_voltage('volt_12.csv')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 18, in brdn_voltage
    a = row[3] #row[N], 
        ~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The thing I don't understand is, why everything was fine for previous 11 files and then all of a sudden - that. For example, this is a fragment of a previous file:
[volt_11.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Q8z.png)
As you can see, there are 4 columns, so by using `row[3]` I should be able to access the last column, and I am.
Now, this is a fragment of a file in question:
[volt_12.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCa5r.png)
Looks absolutely the same to me. But, as it was already stated, using `row[3]` in this file gives an error. Moreover, if I use `row[2]` or `row[1]` etc. it results in the same error. And I honestly don't understand why.
For clarity: the code is identical for all the files.

Comment: "if I use row[2] or row[1] etc. it results in the same error": have you tried printing that row out? If you're getting that error, the index is indeed out of bounds. I'm going to guess that row is an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide your code? It's hard to determine what goes wrong without it.

Comment: If you get an IndexError exception then you can **guarantee** that the subscript is out of bounds. For a non-empty list of length N the valid subscripts are in the inclusive range -N to N-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys! Carcigenicate was right, there is indeed an empty row at the end of the file. I wonder how it got there... Using `if len(row) > 0:` solved the problem.